# Salesforce getting MailingAddress from Contacts

Tags: salesforce

I'm writing an Apex program to go through a list of Contacts and lookup the addresses in another database. Contacts have a built-in MailingAddress field, but accessing the data member gives me a compilation error:

Error: Compile Error: Invalid field MailingAddress for SObject Contact at line 65 column 55

What is the correct way to get the Mailing Address?

Answer (score 8):

The fields are called `MailingStreet, MailingCity, MailingState, MailingPostalCode, MailingCountry`

I'd recommend you find a schema explorer tool and get comfortable with it (e.g. [SoqlX](http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/soqlx/), [apexExplorer](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Tools), [Schema Surfer](http://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wZM3EAM) there are many), they'll help you get upto speed on what all the API names are for the schema in your organization.

Answer (score 1):

All the standard(built in) fields present in the Standard Objects in salesforce can be accessed from the apex code [Salesforce Objects Fields](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index.htm)

This link will provide access to all the standard build in fields. Go to Reference >> Standard Object.